# .NET 6.0 ConfigurationBuilder missing AddJsonFile method

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile(somepath);
```

Error message states

> ConfigurationBuilder does not contain a definition for AddJSONFile.

If I look at the Dependencies/Packages folder this is shown :

> Microsoft.Extensions.Configurations(6.0.1)

This appears to be a missing method in this version of that class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install [`Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json) nuget package.

Also I would suggest to consider [`Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting) nuget which handles a lot of such concerns via [generic hosting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/generic-host) (and depends on the aforementioned package):

> A host is an object that encapsulates an app's resources and lifetime functionality, such as:
>
> - Dependency injection (DI)
> - Logging
> - Configuration
> - App shutdown
> - IHostedService implementations