# Cannot resolve AddJsonFile in .NET 7 Class Library

Tags: c#, .net-7.0

I try to use the following code in .NET 7 Class library.

```
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
.    AddJsonFile(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "appsettings.json")
    .Build();
```

But I get a "Cannot resolve AddJsonFile" error on AddJsonFile. I have added the following references...

- Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
- Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions
- Microsoft.Extensions.Configuratiion.Json

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.NET 6.0 ConfigurationBuilder missing AddJsonFile method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74127366/net-6-0-configurationbuilder-missing-addjsonfile-method)

Comment: Did you use 
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuratiion.Json
Or 
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json  ?